# How do i create a series that I can create a bar chart from

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a list of names:  ['joe','brian','stephen']

i would like to create a bar chart in jupyter with names as indexes and the bar showing the numbers of letters in each name.  How do I create a series which I can call ".plot(kind='bar')" on and get a bar chart like described?

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bars = ['joe','brian','stephen']
height = [len(m) for m in bars]
y_pos = np.arange(len(bars))
plt.bar(y_pos, height, color=(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6))
plt.xticks(y_pos, bars)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x =  ['joe','brian','stephen']
y = [len(m) for m in x]

plt.bar(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: you can also try this answer if you don't want to costume color, positions etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dataframe using your list of names and then apply `len` function.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'names':['joe','brian','stephen']},dtype=str)
df['name_len'] = df['names'].apply(len)

df.plot(kind='bar',x='names')
plt.show()
```

[image]